# Listening with WebSocket Angular app to a REST end point

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, rest, websocket

I already implemented a Spring Boot REST server with some endpoints for Products entity.

In the client-side, which is an Angular application, I want to only listen to the REST endpoints. What I mean is that in contrast to chat apps, there is no need to send messages/products to the server. So the client app only listens for changes.

I am not sure if I should change my Spring Boot REST server to add Websocket functionality or not.

I see a lot of tutorials about Spring boot and chat applications, but I am not sure if that's what I need for my simple application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the communication channel that you will set up between your server and your client is unidirectional, then you must use **server sent events** [1]. In summary, the client will connect to the SSE endpoint by opening an event-streaming request. Here I attach an example on how to connect with curl

```sh
curl --location -X GET 'localhost:8080/sse' \
 -H 'Content-Type: text/event-stream;charset=UTF-8' \
 -H 'Accept: text/event-stream;charset=UTF-8'
```

Note the SSE endpoint is **/sse**. Also note the headers.

[1] https://www.baeldung.com/spring-server-sent-events